# Ordered triples solution to system of equations

Tags: number-theory, multivariable-calculus, contest-math, multilinear-algebra

How many ordered triples  $(x,y,z)$ of integer solutions are there to the following system of equations? 
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+z^2&=194 \\ 
x^2z^2+y^2z^2&=4225
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This, and both the OP's other questions are current problems on brilliant.org.

Comment: This problem is taken from Brilliant, as is all the other posts from this user. I request that you hide the discussion for a week - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $x^2 + y^2 = \dfrac{4225}{z^2}$. Plugging this into the first equation, we get that
$$z^2 + \dfrac{4225}{z^2} = 194 \implies z^2 + \left(\dfrac{65}z\right)^2 = 194$$  Once you have this you should be able to proceed and get the answer.

Comment: So total 32 solutions, right ?

Comment: This problem is taken from Brilliant, as is all the other posts from this user. I request that you hide the discussion for a week - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.

Comment: @CalvinLin I am sorry. I didn't know this before. I have now deleted the main part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$(xz)^2+(yz)^2=65^2 \implies 3|xz$ or $3|yz$

Comment: This problem is taken from Brilliant, as is all the other posts from this user. I request that you hide the discussion for a week - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.